# How can I improve the select speed of my postgres query?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

In my project I have a pretty simple table which looks like this:

```
create table entity
(
    id integer default 1,
    session_id varchar not null,
    type integer not null,
    category integer not null,
    created timestamp default now() not null
)
with (autovacuum_enabled=false);


create index created_index
    on entity (created);
```

I also have a view that selects a grouped result of the entries of the last 30s which looks like this:

```
create view list(type, category, counter) as
    SELECT 
        type,
        category, 
        count(entity.id) AS counter
    FROM entity
    WHERE entity.created >= (now() - '00:00:30'::interval)
    GROUP BY entity.type, entity.category;
```

Because there are no updates or deletes happening to the table I already set it to `unlogged` and disabled auto_vaccuum.

The table has now roughly 20mio entries and the average select time for `SELECT type, category, counter FROM list` is around 2 seconds.

Is there anything I can optimize in order to speed up the selects or is the current speed already the maximum that one can expect from such a large table?

*EDIT:*

This is the output of `EXPLAIN`:

```
Subquery Scan on list  (cost=9.37..9.73 rows=18 width=16) (actual time=425.268..425.278 rows=24 loops=1)
"  Output: list.type, list.category, list.counter “
  Buffers: shared hit=169485
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=9.37..9.55 rows=18 width=16) (actual time=425.267..425.272 rows=24 loops=1)
"        Output: entity.type, entity.category, count(entity.id)
"        Group Key: entity.type, entity.category
        Buffers: shared hit=169485
"        ->  Index Scan using created_index on entity  (cost=0.57..9.13 rows=32 width=12) (actual time=0.050..228.416 rows=165470 loops=1)"
"              Output: entity.id, entity.session_id, entity.type, entity.category, entity.created"
              Index Cond: (entity.created >= (now() - '00:00:30'::interval))
              Buffers: shared hit=169485
Planning Time: 0.204 ms
Execution Time: 425.327 ms
```

The execution time looks pretty good, but this was executed while the system was at rest. Usually there are about 1000 inserts per second into the table.

About the auto-vaccuum, this was a desperate try to see if it improves anything. Should I enable it again?

Comment: Could you show us the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for your query? And do you have an index on (both) entity.type and entity.category ?

Comment: `with (autovacuum_enabled=false)` - why, oh why? That is a really bad idea.

Comment: I added the info above in the post

Comment: @FrankHeikens I only have the index on created

Comment: Execution Time: 425.327 ms to proces 165470 rows. Not really impressive, but also not that slow. But there is a massive difference between the estimated number of rows (32) and the actual number of rows (165470). When did you last ANALYZE this table? And is auto_vacuum (and thus auto_analyze) running?

Comment: create index on entity (created, type, category); might also help

Comment: I created the index and am checking if this help. Does it make sense to optimize the timestamp? I don't need it on milisecond basis, seconds would be enough. Would that make a difference?

Comment: No, that's not going to make any difference, you're still using the same datatype. Does the query plan show any differences? Could you show us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for a [*covering index*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html). If you create a compound index that can satisfy the whole query, you'll have a chance at doing that costly HashAggregate a different way.

Covering indexes typically work best for a limited set of queries. For yours it's this.

```
CREATE INDEX entity_cr_ty_ca_id ON entity(created, type, category) INCLUDE (id);
```

This works well because the query can ....

1. Random-access the index to the first eligible `created` value.
2. Scan the index sequentially. It's a B-TREE index, so the values of `type` and `category` are in a useful order.
3. Pull the `id` value from the index to check whether it's null before doing the COUNT(*).

If you know the `id` values are never null you can simplify this.  Use `COUNT(*)` in place of `COUNT(entity.id)`. And leave `id` out of the index, creating it like this instead.

```
CREATE INDEX entity_cr_ty_ca ON entity(created, type, category);
```

And, it has to be said: even if you get your dbms to generate a large result set quickly, it still has to be transmitted to and interpreted by the program that requests it.  There's no index sorcery that makes that faster.